# Salesforce CPQ: Primary Quote Sharing Settings issue

Tags: cpq, apex-managed-sharing

There can be multiple Quotes on one Opportunity, but only one of them could be marked as a Primary.
It means that if we would create a new Quote with primary checked, it is being unchecked on previous primary Quote.

The issue happens when owner of the previous primary Quote is different than the creator of the new Quote. (because we have set that Quote is Public Read Only in Sharing Settings)

Issue is that with Sharing Settings enabled, even this is being done by a CPQ Trigger - it gives us an error.

I think the CPQ Trigger Handler on Quote object is Apex Class with sharing rules.

Is there any workaround for that?